# How could i get printout of image in android Phone using Wifi Connection instead of using computer?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-wifi

I am developing an app of viewing and editing image for android phones.
I want include an option of print the image that user edited. This options will be inside the app itself using Wifi Connection.

Can any one guide me to get the solution for this problem???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do that i.e. Cloud Printing. Otherwise, there is no easy way. There are a lot of printers and you have integrate their respective SDKs to take printouts.

Comment: i don't have many printers. But, is that possible to done it using wifi only instead of cloud printing.?

Comment: If you want to print some plane text only, then it is simple even without Cloud Printing. If you want to use some text formatting like bold, font size etc. then again the SDK thing comes infront.

Comment: can you give link for printing some texts for reference.

Comment: You can use this sample in AsyncTask or Thread to test the print functionality : 
 try {
   Socket sock = new Socket("10.28.81.65", 9100);
   PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
   os.write("----------------------------------------\r\n");
   os.write("Test Print\r\n\r\n");
   os.write("----------------------------------------\r\n\r\n");
   os.close();
   sock.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }